# JQuery multiple attributes in selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I stumbled upon this form of selector. Notice the quotes, its two attributes.

```
$('#item1','#item2')
```

It seems to return only first element, which is different from $('#item1, #item2') result.  I couldn't find any documentation on what exactly this does. Can somebody explain this or link to documentation with examples please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called context, and it's the same as `find()`, so this:

```
$('#item1','#item2')
```

would equal :

```
$('#item2').find('#item1');
```

in other words, it searched inside `#item2` for an element with the ID `#item1`

To select both elements with ID's `#item1` and `#item2`, you would do:

```
$('#item1, #item2')
```

notice the difference in quotes.

Comment: Basically it means `search #item1 in #item2`.

Comment: @Derek - Yes, search for a child of `#item2` that matched the ID `#item1`.

Answer (score 3):

Selector in Jquery $(param) supports single string parameter and then it split parameter string and then do work for selecting element..

```
$('#item1','#item2') //treat first one param

$('#item1,#item2') //treat one param and splits passed string and will select both
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify any number of selectors to combine into a single result.
This multiple expression combinator is an efficient way to select disparate elements.

**[multiple-selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)**
**[multiple-selector-2](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/multiple)**

```
var list = $("div,p,span").map(function () {
  return this.tagName;
}).get().join(", ");
$("b").append(document.createTextNode(list));
```